# How can I get a transformation-parameters-report (spatial-adjustment)

Tags: coordinate-system, parameters, reports, spatial-adjustment

In ArcGIS resource center about spatial adjustment ([How Transform works](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001300000056000000.htm)), there are transform report like this !

> Scale (X,Y) = (249.927,249.927) Rotation (degrees) = (0.362) 
>   Translation = (2855.407,3715.168) RMS Error (input, output) =
>   (0.118,29.398)
>
> Similarity X =  Ax + By + C
>              Y = -Bx + Ay + F A =   249.922         B =   -1.578 C =   2855.407        F =   3715.168

when I do a transform ,how can i get the report like it ?

Answer (score 1):

The Transform tool generates the report.  Go to the 'Results' pane.  If it has not been activated go to 'Geoprocessing->Results' from the main menu.  In here you can get the reports of all the tools you have run recently, including some historic information.  Find where you ran the Transform tool and click on 'Messages->view'.

The Results pane is a great place.  You can re-run tools from here using identical settings, check on the environment settings you used for a tool and remind yourself of the steps of that amazing geoprocessing process you worked out but can't remember :)